# Lightbox not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, jquery

The Lightbox jquery is not working.
For Photo Gallery it is hover by mouse and zoom in zoom out effect and modal open when user clicks on that

Comment: what is the version, 1.9 or 2? any errors from javascript in browser console ?

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please be specific  with version of magento and show some code along with any console errors that you are using

Comment: magento 2.1.3 version